# EnumerateFiles to avoid caching

Tags: c#, directory

I am using `EnumerateFiles` to get all *.md in the directory:

```
foreach (var mdName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(BaseDirectory,
                            "assets/markdowns"), "*.md", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) 
{
    // async md parser call goes here
}
```

I have three test files `a.md`, `b.md` and `c.md`.

Now when I rename a.md to a1.md, `EnumerateFiles` returns both old and new filename.. The result from PowerShell says I have 3 files, while EnumerateFiles returns 4 files.

I read somewhere EnumerateFiles does some kind of caching, with lazy loading? But shouldn't it *invalidate* cache when the file is renamed?

**GetFiles / EnumerateFiles Output:**

```
[0]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\a.md"
[1]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\b.md"
[2]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\c.md"
[3]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\_a.md"
[4]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\_a1.md"
[5]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\_a2.md"
[6]: "C:\\Repos\\KiddiesBlog\\Tests\\bin\\Debug\\assets/less\\_a3.md"
```

Comment: When exactly are you renaming the file? While the `forach` loop is running or between 2 calls?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, in unit test I was trying different things. The tests were failing. So I removed all the test cases and did everything manually. I was renaming it before foreach. I even tried manual renaming, recompile and rerun the tests. Now its showing 7 files.. File explorer and PowerShell show 3 files.

Comment: from msdn it says it is not caching `The returned collection is not cached; each call to the GetEnumerator on the collection will start a new enumeration`. What happens if you use `GetFiles` instead?

Comment: @SebastianPiu, I restarted VS, cleaned solution and Build it. Same result. Used `GetFile`. Same result..

Comment: FWIW. I am using Git. I did `git stash`. There are only 3 files in origin. No local commits made, no pending commits. Yet `EnumerateFiles` is returning old files.

Comment: I just tried a sample on my local machine and I´m not able to reproduce your error. The code is fine, the must be something else that is out of place

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your 3 files and make VS output the names that is seeing?

Comment: @SebastianPiu, please check the edits. The md files contain 2 sample text lines each.. with chunks enclosed in back tick and asterisk. Nothing fishy there.

Comment: Are you sure those files don't exist? They could be hidden.

Comment: What happens if you output the name + `File.Exists(fullpathtofile)`

Comment: @SebastianPiu, thanks! It was my mistake. There is an MSBuild task responsible for creating shadow copy of the actual assets in `Debug` directory.  It has all the previous files. VS isn't clearing the folder on Clean Solution. I guess I need to modify this task to observe the changes. Thanks you again for all the insights. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be my mistake. There is an `MSBuild` task responsible for creating shadow copy of the actual assets in Debug directory. It has all the previous files. VS isn't clearing the folder on Clean Solution. I guess I need to modify this task to observe the changes in source directory.